# trying to prove that a span is a basis for another set

Tags: vector-spaces

> Let $S=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3\end{bmatrix}\vert2x_1+x_2-2x_3=0\right\}$ and $\mathcal B=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ -2 \\ 0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 2 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}\right\}$. Prove that $\mathcal B$ is a basis for $S$.

I know that the correct way to solve this question is to prove that $S$ is a subset of $\mathcal B$ and $\mathcal B$ is a subset of $S$ so that $\mathcal B$ is a basis for $S$.
I managed to prove that $S$ is a subset of span $\mathcal B$, but cannot prove $\mathcal B$ is a subset of $S$.
Please help me do it and show me complete procedure. Thanks!

Comment: What else does it mean for something to be a basis?

Comment: Here $S$ contains infinitely many elements, and $B$ contains exactly two elements.  Thus it is impossible that $S$ is a subset of $B$, though perhaps $S$ is a subset of the *span* of $B$.  You should be able to easily show $B \subset S$ by checking the property that defines $S$.

Answer (score 0):

To show $\mathcal{B}\subset S$ we simply need to show that the respective $x_1,x_2,x_3$ coordinates satisfy the "defining rule" of $S$. So we want $2x_1+x_2-2x_3=0$ when either $x_1=1,x_2=-2,x_3=0$ or $x_1=0,x_2=2,x_3=1$.

We also need to show $\mathcal{B}$ is linearly independent. Since $\mathcal{B}$ only has two elements, it is sufficient to note that one is not a scalar multiple of the other.

For completeness, I'll show $S\subseteq\text{span}(B)$ so you can check your answer. Suppose $\mathbf{x}\in S$. Then
$$\mathbf{x}=\left[\begin{array}{c}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3
\end{array}\right]$$
where $2x_1+x_2-2x_3=0$. This is equivalent to saying $x_2=-2x_1+2x_3$, so we can write
$$\mathbf{x}=\left[\begin{array}{c}
x_1\\
-2x_1+2x_3\\
x_3
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}
x_1\\
-2x_1\\
0
\end{array}\right]+\left[\begin{array}{c}
0\\
2x_3\\
x_3
\end{array}\right]=x_1\left[\begin{array}{c}
1\\
-2\\
0
\end{array}\right]+x_3\left[\begin{array}{c}
0\\
2\\
1
\end{array}\right]$$
which you should be able to recognise as belonging to $\text{span}(\mathcal{B})$.

Comment: thank you, i understand what you mean. but i am not sure how to write the first part properly. could you please help me?

Comment: Yeah, no problem. Since $2\cdot1+(-2)+2\cdot0=0$, we have that $\left[\begin{array}{c}
1\\
-2\\
0
\end{array}\right]\in S$. Similarly, $\left[\begin{array}{c}
0\\
2\\
1
\end{array}\right]\in S$ since $2\cdot0+2-2\cdot1=0$.